# Project an array in jsonb

Tags: postgresql

Suppose we have this table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEST (FIELD jsonb);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('[{"key": 1},{"key": 2}]');
SELECT field FROM TEST;
```

Result:

```
field
[{"key": 1}, {"key": 2}]
```

I would like to query the table in order to obtain this result:

```
field
[1, 2]
```

that is, to project every element in the array respect to their `key`.

Can't find a simple way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSON path query:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query_array(field, '$[*].key') 
FROM test;
```

`[*]` iterates over all values in the array and `.key` then returns the value for each key.